# Memory ordering issues

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-fences

I'm experimenting with C++0x support and there is a problem, that I guess shouldn't be there. Either I don't understand the subject or gcc has a bug.

I have the following code, initially `x` and `y` are equal. Thread 1 always increments `x` first and then increments `y`. Both are atomic integer values, so there is no problem with the increment at all. Thread 2 is checking whether the `x` is less than `y` and displays an error message if so.

This code fails sometimes, but why? The issue here is probably memory reordering, but all atomic operations are sequentially consistent by default and I didn't explicitly relax of those any operations. I'm compiling this code on x86, which as far as I know shouldn't have any ordering issues. Can you please explain what the problem is?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

std::atomic_int x;
std::atomic_int y;

void f1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        ++x;
        ++y;
    }
}

void f2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (x < y)
        {
            std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    std::thread t1(f1);
    std::thread t2(f2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

The result can be viewed [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6364fdac50945ef5338abf5e86072aea).

Comment: Actually this is experimental implementation of C++0x, so the second one is possible, but I believe the first one is more likely :P

Comment: The code posted above will always produce `"error"`, (`x` will always be greater than or equal to `y`) is this what you wanted?

Comment: Why if (x < y) should be always true, if x will always be greater than or equal to y?

Comment: What is the default memory ordering for the increment?  Does a store guarantee a release?  [My experience with the C++0x memory model is limited]

Comment: @Paul: I immediately agreed with you, but you and I were thinking "if it's *not* what he tests, print `"error"`. But the code is if it *is*, print it.Thread 2 can see pairs of the form `(n, n)` and `(n + 1, n)`. In both cases, `x < y` is false. There is one sequence that triggers it, though. @James: Yeah.

Comment: "What is the default memory ordering for the increment?" - sequentially consistent is default.

Comment: @confucius:  I figured; a relaxed ordering by default would be terrible.

Comment: @GMan: You're right of course. I think I've spent far too long looking at code for one day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem could be in your test:

```
if (x < y)
```

the thread could evaluate `x` and not get around to evaluating `y` until much later.

Comment: I guess that is the problem, the question is why? Actually sequentially consistent atomic operations must prevent this, mustn't they?

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem is unspecified sequence of expression evaluation, so simple :)

Comment: @confucius: while your scenario might have a dependency on the order that the variables might be read, the more general issue is that reading 2 different atomic instances isn't atomic.

Comment: Of course, I think in the current situation misleading line in the code was (x < y) condition, which hides implicit load operations. (x.load() < y.load()) instead would make it easier to see.

Answer (score 13):

There is a problem with the comparison:

```
x < y
```

The order of evaluation of subexpressions (in this case, of `x` and `y`) is unspecified, so `y` may be evaluated before `x` or `x` may be evaluated before `y`.

If `x` is read first, you have a problem:

```
x = 0; y = 0;
t2 reads x (value = 0);
t1 increments x; x = 1;
t1 increments y; y = 1;
t2 reads y (value = 1);
t2 compares x < y as 0 < 1; test succeeds!
```

If you explicitly ensure that `y` is read first, you can avoid the problem:

```
int yval = y;
int xval = x;
if (xval < yval) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it. Sorry guys, cannot plus, https is blocked in the office and I can't login :(

Answer (score 4):

Every now and then, `x` will wrap around to 0 just before `y` wraps around to zero. At this point `y` will legitimately be greater than `x`.

Comment: Took a shot at editing it. It might as well be noted that signed overflow leads to undefined behavior, though unsigned overflow wraps as expected.

Comment: Agree. Overflow was not supposed to happen, it was done just for test, but this could be a problem too. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

First, I agree with "Michael Burr" and "James McNellis". Your test is not fair, and there's a legitime possibility to fail. However even if you rewrite the test the way "James McNellis" suggests the test may fail.

First reason for this is that you don't use `volatile` semantics, hence the compiler may do optimizations to your code (that are supposed to be ok in a single-threaded case).

But even with `volatile` your code is not guaranteed to work.

I think you don't fully understand the concept of *memory reordering*. Actually memory read/write reorder can occur at two levels:

1. Compiler may exchange the order of the generated read/write instructions.
2. CPU may execute memory read/write instructions in arbitrary order.

Using `volatile` prevents the (1). However you've done nothing to prevent (2) - memory access reordering by the **hardware**.

To prevent this you should put special **memory fence** instructions in the code (that are designated for CPU, unlike `volatile` which is for compiler only).

In x86/x64 there're many different memory fence instructions. Also every instruction with `lock` semantics by default issues full memory fence.

More information here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier

Comment: valdo - no need to use volatile here, because memory barriers by default generated by C++0x atomic operations prevent both (1) and (2).